# Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported for first word, TAB lisits possible command completions

Tags: 14.04, boot, grub2, grub-efi

I am currently new to Ubuntu and facing this problem, tried the grub method and the live boot usb method with bood repair it shows me:
 your boot has been successfully repaired but still I get out of this problem. 
https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-deal-with-Fix-Minimal-BASH-like-line-editing-is-supported-GRUB-Error-In-Linux and even the boot repair method but unable to fix this.
I have uploaded [some images](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1pTvuKOCT5Okj-Dn28aqzLSYhJ6S1CDKL) in my google drive as I was unable to upload it over here 
 I don't want to lose my data and get back my files from the system.

For any help in advance, thank you.

Comment: When you get the grub prompt, run the command `ls (hd0, 1)/` also try `ls (hd0, 4)/`. Which one of those lists the file *vmlinuz*?

Comment: @Paul Benson its says unknown file system on ls (hd0,1) where as on ls (hd0.4) it shows Filesystem is ext2.

Comment: Really? Neither of those 2 commands list anything? Did you include the forward slash at the end? If so try `ls (hd1, 1)/` and `ls hd1, 4)/`?

Comment: Yes i have uploaded the image on the drive you can have a look at that. @Paul Benson

Comment: I have tried all method @Paul Benson even i had done it with ls (hd0 ,3)/ and ls (hd0,2)/

Comment: You don't need to `ls (hd0, 3)/`. That's your boot partition. I was looking for your root partition, which appears to be missing or corrupted. Which sda partition holds your data, and did you back this up before this issue?

Comment: @Paul Benson my all are in sda4 no i don't have any back.

Comment: I guessed it might be with the *Harsh* folder. Boot up from UB. Live, and run `sudo parted -l` and post image of output.

Comment: @Paul Benson i ran the command and got the output of all the disk partition which i have uploaded in the drive again

Comment: Did you take the images before or after you did the boot-repair? The boot-repair log shows valid disk partitions, but the images don't. Tell us the EXACT sequence of what happened from the time that the system worked, to now.

Comment: @heynnema yesterday my system freezed after that i had to make a shutdown from the switch after that i got grub loader and was trying many things but nothing worked out for me. I first tried to get it out from the grub command but it was not working.

Comment: OK. I suggest you try to do a re-install from Live UB. Run `sudo gparted`, click Partition, select **sda1** and delete. You will then have unallocated space, and use that to reinstall UB. I would also recommend you back up your data from sda4 before you do this, just to be safe.

Comment: Thanks @Paul Benson i will try to make it resolve. I think its issue in the mount.

Comment: You said you shutdown from the switch button. That suggests that sda1 is corrupted. You won't be able to fix it if fsck didn't work. Since grub prompt also failed to find the kernel vmlinuz you will need to reinstall. Your choice.

Comment: @Paul Benson thank you for the help and letting me find out the problem. I have made it and my files have been recovered and i have posted my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was with the filesystem as my mount and kernel file where missing or corrupt.
The only was to install Ubuntu again and do manual file allocation. 
The steps which i figured it out was.

Step1 : make a live usb.

Step2 : was to start live Ubuntu 14.04.06 and use gparted to remove the /boot/efi (if you have made it while installing as i made it)partition on my computer and make it a free space. Make sure you don't delete any other partition which may cause you problems.

Step 3: start the installation of ubuntu.

Step 4: on the page of installation type select something else as it allows you to manually partition the hard drive.

Step 5: as the manual step start you would see your other partition. Then you need to delete the swap area and make new swap area and /boot/efi partition make sure you don't make any other partition delete. 
Then change the mount of the file as made earlier while installing (i had 4 partition / as ext4, /home as ext4 , boot loader and swap area.) So i did change / to once again from do not use this partition to  / and ext4 and /home and ext4 for my home partition.

Step 6: i even made the same user name and password as earlier as i was not confirm weather i would get my files back or not.
So i recommend it.

Step 7: then i started my installation and make sure you don't format the other partition (in my case / and /home). When it give you warning prompt for installation of the .
Let it install success Fully and once installed.
You can recover your file and data.( as in my case all the data where in /home directory.)
And re-install Ubuntu as some problem might occur.
So i Highly recommend to re-install after data recovery.

Answer (score 0):

To check your file system...

For 18.04 or newer...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda1`
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sda4`
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

Comment: I have already tried this but this didn't work out before. But still i will try it again.

Comment: @Harsh status please...

Comment: It didn't worked as my mound and kernel file have some problem. But i made it through some other way

Comment: thank you for the help sir. I posted in the answer section who i made it work.